# Enable firewall rule with powershell for Domain only

Tags: powershell, windows-firewall

How to get CimInstance of specific NetFirewallProfile with powershell 4?

I try to automate enabling existing firewall rule that allows to use MS DTC for Domain "network type" like throug GUI
[image]

```
Enable-NetFirewallRule –DisplayGroup “Distributed Transaction Coordinator”
```

sets all checkboxes

Cmdlet `Enable-NetFirewallRule` has `AssociatedNetFirewallProfile` parameter but it's of type `CimInstance` not `String`. There is also `Get-NetFirewallProfile` but I cannot use it to populate the parameter nor through pipeline neither as variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to fetch the profile and supplying it, you can use [`Get-NetFirewallRule`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554860(v=wps.630).aspx) to find the rule (with the profile) and pipe it into [`Enable-NetFirewallRule`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554869(v=wps.630).aspx).

As an example you could use the following, assuming that "Distributed Transaction Coordinator" is the name of the actual rule:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | Where {$_.Name -eq "Distributed Transaction Coordinator" -and $_.Profile -eq "Domain"} | Enable-NetFirewallRule
```

Furthermore you should be able to use [`Get-NetFirewallProfile`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573830(v=wps.630).aspx) to fetch the object of a profile into a variable and supply it.

Comment: Filtering `Get-NetFirewallRule` solved my problem. Thanks. Your second suggestion I mentioned in last sentence of my original post - it does not work for me.

Comment: Now I've figured it out that those rules were existed due to my first experiments with GUI. On clean system I need to create them not just enable.

Comment: Careful with the `$_Profile -eq "Domain"` -- `Profile` is actually an enum, and if it's set to Domain and another profile (e.g. Private), then the `-eq` won't work.

Comment: Good point. `Profile` is actually a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.NetSecurity.Profile` but there seems to be an implicit conversion to a string. As such an easy workaround would be to use `-like '*Domain*'` instead of `-eq`.